# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField problem to save data in DB

Tags: django, modelmultiplechoicefield

I used to have a Multi select box in my form filled with a JSON list

forms.py

```
FRUIT_CHOICES= [
    ('Oranges', 'Oranges'),
    ('Cantaloupes', 'Cantaloupes'),
    ('Mangoes', 'Mangoes'),
    ('Honeydews', 'Honeydews')
    ]

class AddRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    testrever = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=FRUIT_CHOICES)
```

And so I used a JSON field in my models.py like this

models.py

```
class Record(models.Model):
    testrever = models.JSONField(max_length=500)
```

It worked like a charm and I was able to save the selection and load it back when the form was recalled.

But now in `forms.py` I need to modify the `forms.MultipleChoiceField` to `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` which is populated by a queryset like this

```
class AddRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.storage_pk = kwargs.pop('pk')
        super(AddRecordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['testrever'].queryset = BDC.objects.filter(ref=self.storage_pk).values_list('model', flat=True) 


    testrever = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.widgets.SelectMultiple, queryset=None)

class Meta:
    model = Record
    exclude = ("user",)
    fields = ['id','first_name','last_name','email', 'phone' ,'address', 'city' ,'state' ,'zipcode' ,'regarde' ,'testrever']
```

So now my `models.JSONField` in `models.py` is no longer working since I'm not rendering a JSON list format anymore.

**What kind of field should I use in `models.py` to make it work again?**

Comment: Use a `ManyToManyField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pick zero, one or multiple items of another model, you use a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Djangp-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField):

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return name


class Record(models.Model):
    testrever = models.ManyToManyField(Fruit, blank=True)
```

This also uses a `ModelMultipleChoice` field as default form field. So you only have to plug in a different widget:

```
class RecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'testrever': forms.SelectMultiple}
```

while most databases offer a JSON field nowadays, which is useful for *unstructered* data, for structured data, using a `JSONField` is not a good idea as it violates [*first normal form* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still don't get it though (sorry)  what is the class Fruit for ? since I want to populate the widget with a queryset in class AddRecordForm?  Should i get rid of the forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField in forms.py ?   i don't get the widgets = {'testrever': forms.SelectMultiple} part either as i specify it in the forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.widgets.SelectMultiple.  already

Comment: And thanks for the advice about JSONField, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Nico44044: since you used `FRUIT_CHOICES` I used the model `Fruit`, but likely here it is `BDC`, you can indeed still set the queryset in the constructor as you did.

Comment: I made the changes as you told but i have an error : (1146, "Table 'data.website_record_testrever' doesn't exist") It adds "_testrever" at the end and I don't know why. It appens because of this line in models.py  in the class Record: testrever = models.ManyToManyField(BDC, blank=True)

Comment: @`Nico44044: because an m2m is implemented as a junction table in a relational database. You need to make migrations and migrate the database.

Comment: Ok. My database is Mysql do you think it’s a problem ? Is there something special to do as create a new table ? Or  do i just have to make django migration from manage.py ? Sorry it’s my first django app …

Comment: @Nico44044: you use `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` to create a migration, that migration will construct the junction table.

Comment: I did the migration but I have this message error : "TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use testrever.set() instead."

Comment: @Nico44044: that is by assigning it with the model form? You can indeed not make a `Record(testrever=...)` for example, or `my_record.testrever = ...` but that is than likely in a view. since a `ModelForm` can handle that properly.